# Are any two elements indistinguishable by a single measure?

Tags: elements

Elements can be investigated using a range of different techniques to determine their fundamental properties.

> Some properties of an element can be observed only in a collection of atoms or molecules of the element. These properties include **color, density, melting point, boiling point, and thermal and electrical conductivity**.
>
> <sub><sup>[Infoplease: Properties of the Elements](https://www.infoplease.com/encyclopedia/science-and-technology/chemistry/chemistry-general/element/properties-of-the-elements)</sup></sub>

Are there any two stable(ish) elements that are completely indistinguishable in terms of their fundamental properties **by a single measure?**

That is to say, if I investigated one element to the *absolute limit of human technology in that one specific measure*, I wouldn't be able to tell one element from another?

Comment: Closest I can think off the top of my head is iridium and osmium, whose densities in ambient conditions differ by 0.13%. This is within measurement error for even rather accurate analysis methods, but obviously still the realm of possibility. Similarly, there have been attempts to make fake gold bars with tungsten, whose densities differ by around 0.25%, and you can believe there was significant economic pressure to tell the difference.

Comment: Nd and Pr are so similar that it is very difficult to separate them: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1002072118309918. Zr and Hf are another example.

Comment: Can you explain better what do you mean by "single measure"? Do you mean if there are elements with identical physical properties? (Same identical density?) because a lot will depend on the accuracy of your measurements (see Nicolau answer.. 0.13% is not a lot but it is still a difference)

Comment: @Jojostack - That's exactly it. Are there any elements with (for example) completely the same density? That if you measured their density *and density alone, to the maximal limit of human science*, that you still couldn't tell one from the other.

Comment: @Jojostack -"*Fakeium and Notrealium have similar melting points. So similar in fact, that modern science cannot tell them apart..."* That sort of thing.

Comment: @Valorum Every measurement comes with errors, which either can be of systematic (relating to accuracy), or random origin (relating to precision; for a discern of the two, see e.g. Wikipedia's illustrations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision)). It hence depends on the method deployed and distribution of individual measurements about sample A and sample B if the two are significantly different from each other to distinguish the samples as about different elements (e.g., [Student $t$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test)).

Comment: This question seems to be attracting a bunch of downvotes but without explanation. Anyone care to suggest scope for improvement?

Comment: If I make the 'fundamental property' to be only crystal structure at STP, then there are many fcc, bcc, or hcp elements. If instead it is crystal structure and lattice parameters at STP, then the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

*The absolute limit of human technology*, huh? While it's technically impossible to prove a negative, the answer is almost certainly **no**, at least in spirit. The problem is that [metrology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrology) is just too powerful!

Let's do a very crude analysis. We know 118 elements, and say there are 100 "reasonable" experimental properties for each. Nowadays, metrological studies can determine a wide variety of physical parameters with 5 or more significant digits. Let's say that the measurements are perfectly random within that range. That means you have 118 attempts at pulling 100 balls with replacement out of a box with 100 000 balls, and you hope to pull the same ball out twice. That probability is about 11%, which isn't very high.

If there is a way around it, you have to stack the odds in your favor. Not every physical quantity can be measured with the same accuracy in different contexts. For example, while something like LIGO can [implicitly measure changes in distance up to ~22 significant digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO#Operation), it turns out that precisely measuring volumes of macroscopic objects (which are fundamentally distances cubed) is tricky due to shape variability. What that means is certain volume-dependent properties, most obviously density, may be comparatively difficult to measure precisely.

And it turns out that there are a few elements which happen to have similar densities. Presumably for over 100 years, it was known that either osmium or iridium was the densest of the stable elements, but it was hard to definitely say which. It took arguably until 1989 for the matter to be settled by a [combination of x-ray crystallography measurements](https://web.archive.org/web/20120207064113/http://www.platinummetalsreview.com/pdf/pmr-v33-i1-014-016.pdf), which determined the density of osmium to be about 0.12% larger than iridium (22.588 ± 0.015 g/cm³ and 22.562 ± 0.009 g/cm³, respectively). There are a few other pairs of elements whose densities differ on the order of 1%, and I don't know to what accuracy their densities have been established, so you could say there is still room for overlap confusion.

But even then, this is only true when comparing the data we have *currently*. In reality, though, the vast majority of properties measured for elements has *not* been performed with the "absolute limit of human technology" backing them, because that's very expensive. Usually it's just a few labs around the world working semi-independently with standard amounts of funding. However, when there *is* a strong coordinated international effort to determine such quantities, then it may be possible to tack on as many as 3-4 additional significant figures on demand.

I mentioned how density measurements are typically constrained by volume errors. Well, a few years ago we had [the Avogadro project](https://www.nist.gov/si-redefinition/kilogram/kilogram-silicon-spheres-and-international-avogadro-project) as part of a drive to change the definition of the kilogram. This eventually resulted in the manufacture of 99.9999999% pure, monocrystalline, [99.9999%-perfect spheres of silicon-28](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZMByI4s-D-Y) (99.99% isotopic purity) and [ultimately allowed determination](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.106.030801) of the macroscopic density of the silicon-28 isotope to 7 significant digits (approximately 2.320071 ± 0.000002 g/cm³). The same technology could be applied to silicon with a natural isotopic abundance for slightly less precision, to determine a true density for elemental silicon. Other elements would require modifications to the techniques, but it's conceivable that similar precision could be obtained, and it would be enough to distinguish every element with virtual certainty. There is no reason to assume similar disambiguation cannot be performed for every other reasonable physical property.